# Get elements that have not been added to the DOM

Tags: javascript

If I create a new HTML element using `document.createElement`, but I do not add it to the DOM, is there a way to find it? As this is a method of `document`, it seems somewhat logical that it might become property of `document`.

Example:

```
(function(){
    document.createElement("a");
})();

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("a").length); // -> 0
```

I understand why the above example doesn't work. Is there an alternative?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make an array of all elements of a type that have been created, whether or not they have been added to the DOM.

Comment: That is impossible in general, and any practical solution for some sub cases would be a lot of work.

Comment: ...in a third party script that may be loaded after the elements have been created,

Comment: I'm not saying I'd suggest it, but you could also override `document.createElement` to keep track of elements you create. As well as counting with `.getElementsByTagName()`

Comment: @Ian that is not even the most common way of creating elements.. `.innerHTML` is. See my first comment.

Comment: Just check the `parentNode` property, it will be `null` if the element is not in the dom tree, it will hold an object otherwise.

Comment: @Esailija That's a great point, I didn't think of that. I was really only responding to what the OP was using in their code, but I realize that's not everything

Comment: Using `.innerHTML` isn't an issue. Either that adds an element to the DOM or it adds it to an element I would already have recorded with the overwritten `.createElement`. My problem is finding elements that were created before my script ran. But the consensus seems to be (as I thought), that this is not possible.

Comment: @ColBeseder Right, but I think what they were referring to was something like `var a = document.createElement("div"); a.innerHTML = "HTML stuff";` - you can't "override" setting `.innerHTML` and find the `"HTML STUFF"` like you can with `document.createElement`

Answer (score 3):

You're just creating some elements, without insterting them in the DOM.

You need to store them if you want to know how many they are.

```
var myElements = []:
var elem = document.createElement("a");
myElements.push(elem);
myElements.length; // use their length for your needs
```

Comment: So you're saying that it isn't possible to get a full list after the fact?

Comment: No, there _is_ no list, unless you keep one yourself.

Comment: Calling document.createElement("a") without assigning it to a var (or keep reference) in a global scope or another scope makes it automatically garbage collected and won't be accessible

Comment: But if it is an `img` (for example), the image will still be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating elements in several different functions then you need to update the global array:

```
var linkElements = []; //declared in global

function addLinkElements()
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");

    // add link element to global array
    linkElements.push(link);

    // total link elements
    alert( "Total anchors: " + linkElements.length + document.getElementsByTagName("a") );
}
```

Note: Remember to remove update the array in all functions adding these link elements.

hope that helps.